# How to fix flicker when we want to remove border and box-shadow on hovering

Tags: css, border

The problem statement:

1. a `div` has a gray border and a box-shadow
2. the task is to clear border and shadow when div hovered
3. we get rid of them by `border:none` and `box-shadow:none`
4. a flicker appears

```css
#test{
  border:2px gray solid;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px gray;
  width:160px;
  height:100px; background:url('http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-screen-lg')
}

#test:hover{
  box-shadow:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `border-color:transparent` instead of `border:none`

```
#test:hover{
  box-shadow:none;
  border-color:transparent;
}
```

```css
#test{
  border:2px gray solid;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px gray;
  width:160px;
  height:100px; background:url('http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-screen-lg')
}

#test:hover{
  box-shadow:none;
  border-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```